# Is there a way to push Helm charts with different name an AWS ECR registry?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-helm, helm3

The AWS user guide says that the name of my repository should match the name the Helm chart that I want to push [1] but in my use case I want to have a single ECR repository with different Helm charts in it.

Is there any workaround to achieve this?

1: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/push-oci-artifact.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround that worked for me was to name my charts with the same name as the ECR repository and diffrentiate between them in the version section.

project1/Chart.yaml:

```yaml
name: aws-ecr-repo-name
description: My cool helm chart for project1
type: application
version: 0.2.0-project1
appVersion: "1.16.0"
```

project2/Chart.yaml:

```yaml
name: aws-ecr-repo-name
description: My cool helm chart for project2
type: application
version: 0.2.0-project2
appVersion: "1.16.0"
```